# How to mark a message as read , \Seen on IMAP ( Go )

Tags: go, imap

I'm trying to mark a message/list of messages as "[\SEEN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-11)" (permanently) using [IMAP](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap) . However  unlike fetch, search and friends there seem to be no Flag function on the imap package. Should I send raw commands with the UIDs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select the mailbox as writable

```
youImapConnection.Select(mailboxName, false) // true would be for readonly
```

And then simply do the following

```
seq, _ := imap.NewSeqSet("")
err := seq.AddNum(612) // 612 is your UID
_, err = imap.Wait(youImapConnection.UIDStore(seq, "+FLAGS", imap.NewFlagSet(`\Seen`))) // Here you tell to add the flag \Seen
```

Finally you will have to expunge:

```
_, err := imap.Wait(youImapConnection.Close(true)) // Here you tell to apply changes, necessary if you mark an Email as deleted
```

And you should be good :-)

And do not hesitate to browse the doc/source code, it's easy to understand and you'll find all you need.

Comment: that seems to work. Any idea how to set it unread ? I've tried to send "null" as per RFC but it doesn't work.  As a side note I'm wondering why the GO team didn't just added some enums / constants with all the possible  flags & attributes

Comment: Nvm I've found  it... it should be ``-FLAGS`. The imap specs are a f*** mess.

Comment: The Imap protocol is a real mess, but you should find all the information your need either in the source code, or by reading the different relevant RFC. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

IMAP uses the `STORE` command to set flags on messages, e.g.:

```
foo UID STORE 135211 +FLAGS (\Seen)
```

So I'd guess that you should use the [`Store`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap#Client.Store) or [`UIDStore`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap#Client.UIDStore) functions to set flags.

Comment: There even seems to be a [`FlagSet`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap#FlagSet) type that can hold several flags at once.