# How to search ALL Unread messages IMAP CMD / go

Tags: go, imap

I'm developing an email client and for some reasons the IMAP server doesn't send me back all the unread messages. Out of 2915 emails it sends back  only 2888. I've tried to mark them as read/unread consecutively and it seems that the "Read" command works and marks them all read, unread works too but when I search for unread messages I get don't get 27 of them.

Any hint as to why that happens? I suspect there is an IMAP glitch.

Some code

```
const (
    //serch
    SearchUnseen = "UNSEEN"
    SearchSeen   = "SEEN"
    SearchALL    = "ALL"
)
const (
    FlagSeen   = `\Seen`
    FlagUnseen = `\Unseen`
)

const (
    //flag types
    FlagSet    = "+FLAGS"
    FlagRemove = "-FLAGS"
)

type Request struct {
    Label string //label: INBOX, Sent
    Attr  string //attr: RFC822.HEADER , []BODY if is Fetch
    //OR "ALL", "UNSEEN" if is SEARCH
    //http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4
    SqID string //sequences 1:44 , 1:*, 1,2,3 (UID)
}

cmd, err = c.UIDSearch(set, r.Attr)



cmd, err := imap.Wait(c.UIDStore(set, flagAction, imap.NewFlagSet(flag)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
```

Comment: Can you get hold of the actual data being sent and received on the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing some really weird things and you should read how Imap and the lib work.

To sum up.

You have to select your mailbox depending on what you will want to achieve. If you want to only download email select it as read only. If you want to update some emails(seen, deleted) select it as writable. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916179/how-to-mark-a-message-as-read-seen-on-imap-go/24917274#24917274).

If you want to download a list of UIDS, simply use `UIDSearch` with only one arg specifying the range you want to get. You can use `UIDSearch("1:*")`

If you want to get the UIDs of the unread emails: `UIDSearch("1:* NOT SEEN")`

UIDSearch does NOT care about `Attr` since it will only get UIDS and not bodys.

If you want the body, use `UIDFetch` and give it a `*imap.SeqSet` with the differents attributes you want to get. Example: `UIDFetch(set, "RFC822.HEADER", "UID")`

To sum up, read the [documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/mxk/go-imap/imap#Client.UIDSearch) or browse the code with [sourceGraph](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mxk/go-imap)(really awesome)